# Insert line break in textarea when pressing enter, but don't submit form

Tags: jquery

I have a form with multiple text fields and textareas, among others.
When I press enter the form is sent.
I have solved this with:

```
$('form').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

But then pressing enter in the textarea does not insert a line break. It does nothing.

Then I tried:

```
$('body').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.target.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA') {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then the form is sent by pressing enter. I do not know how to fix it. I tried this:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("ad_text");
        textarea.value += "\n";
        // I'm guessing you may want this
        return false;
    }
});
```

Good idea, but the line break is always inserted at the end, instead of at the current editing position.

Another thing I tried is:

```
$.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
    var elem = $(this).get(0);
    var pos = 0;
    if ('selectionStart' in elem) {
        pos = elem.selectionStart;
    } else if ('selection' in document) {
        elem.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var selLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        sel.moveStart('character', -elem.value.length);
        pos = sel.text.length - selLength;
    }
    return pos;
} 
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function (pos) {
    this.each(function (index, elem) {
        if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
            elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
        }
    });
    return this;
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('textarea').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var pos = $("#ad_text").getCursorPosition();
            var valorInput = $("#ad_text").val();
            var miValor1=valorInput.substring(pos, pos + 1);
            //aqui poner algun if si pos se encuentra al final de la cadena se pone   var miValor2= valorInput.replace(miValor1,  miValor1  + "\r" )

            var miValor2= valorInput.replace(miValor1, "\r" + miValor1  )

            $("#ad_text").val(miValor2);
            $("#ad_text").setCursorPosition(pos + 1);

            return false;
        }
    });
    $('form').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('input').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

This works pretty well, but eventually produces text line breaks, it does at the beginning of the text,
I decided to put some "if" but I can not think of anything.

Using joomla template:
yoo_nite

And I've reviewed all js files and I found that when I delete the file
uikit.js the textarea works well, but other things do not work.

Also when I change template it works fine.

But this is a template developed by me and I do not want to change it.

The site is
http://alanuncio.com/alanuncioitechno/index.php?option=com_adsmanager&view=edit&Itemid=106

Comment: I say let the form submit if you press enter, or set a different default button.  You're trying to break the way the web was designed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if you press enter in a textarea, it does *not* submit a form. That means there must be some other script doing it.

On another part of your page you have the following script:

```
jeams(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(keycode == 13) {
        if(jeams("input#buscador").val() == 'Buscar...') jeams("input#buscador").val('');
        jeams('#form_ajaxSearch')[0].submit();
    }
});
```

It submits the search box when the enter key is pressed, but it detects the enter key *anywhere on the page*, including the text area.

I believe if you change `jeams(document)` to `jeams("input#buscador")` it should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help.
You have solved my problem.
I could not find a month so you have helped me a lot.
Not because I can not give you a vote of reputation.
I think because I'm new to stackoverflow community.
But when I go to give it to you.
SOLVED